# How to compare the size of two lists and return a larger list?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that will return the larger of the two lists.

```
List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>(); // size 50
List<String> lastNames = new ArrayList<String>(); // size 1000
```

I want to compare their size and return a larger list. Something like this.

```
public List<String> largerList (List firstNames, List lastNames) {
return max.size(firstNames, lastNames);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not size? What is the factor

Comment: These are not arrays they are lists.  And what if you wanted to compare two of `List<Integer>` or two of `List<SomeClass>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<String> largerArray (List firstName, List lastName) {
    return firstName.size() > lastName.size() ? firstName : lastName;
}
```

Although your use case is not very clear. If firstName is a list then ideally it must be named as firstNames, if its not the case then i am not sure what exactly you’re trying to do there

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the sizes, and then choose which list to return.
Also, don't forget to check that the list is not null, before accessing an instance method (`.size()`)

```
public List<?> largerArray (List<?> l1, List<?> l2) {
    int lengthOfL1 = l1 == null ? 0 : l1.size();
    int lengthOfL2 = l2 == null ? 0 : l2.size();

    return (lengthOfL1 > lengthOfL2) ? l1 : l2;
}
```

note: by using a wildcard (`?`) you can accept ANY two lists, so you will be able to compare a list of strings with a list of Integers, if this is something that you want

Comment: This doesn't work.  Did you try it?

Comment: @WJS 
I did, and it works just fine for me

Comment: Create two `List<Integer>`  and call it  as `List<Integer> result = largerArray(list1,list2);`

Comment: @WJS well your return type will also be a List<?>, not List<Integer>
```List<?> result = largerArray(list1,list2);``` works fine. a casting will be necessary.

Comment: But that's useless unless you cast.  Do that and try `int x = result.get(0);` `List<?>` means a list of unknown type.

Comment: @WJS yes there are disadvantages for this method, but it allows you to compare lists of different types since you are interested just in the length. the solution you suggested in this question will not accept ```List<Integer>``` and ```List<String>```. so it depends on OP's requirements as to which implementation will work best.

Answer (score 0):

Write a static generic method to compare two lists of the same type.

```
List<Integer> list1 = List.of(1,2,3,4);
List<Integer> list2 = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
    
List<Integer> result = getLargest(list1,list2);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

- uses the ternary operator to do the compare
- if they are equal in size, returns `list2`.

```
public static <T> List<T> getLargest(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
     Objects.requireNonNull(list1);
     Objects.requireNonNull(list2);
     return list1.size() > list2.size() ? list1 : list2;
}
```